# Converting iOS ASIHttpRequest project to ARC but receive fatal error

Tags: ios, automatic-ref-counting, asihttprequest

I have added the following compiler flag to all ASI related files: `-fno-objc-arc`

I try to convert my project to ARC, but I receive the following error:

> fatal error: file 'ASIHttpRequest/Classes/ASICacheDelegate.h' has been modified since the precompiled header 'Build/Intermediates/PrecompiledHeaders/MyProject-Prefix-dhhqfujcvuzqszfkhfmydmxjavrm/MyProject-Prefix.pch.pch' was built

I believe part of the problem is that the file ASICacheDelegate.h is in my project, but not in the list of compiled sources for me to add the compiler flag to.

How can I either resolve this error or add this file to my compile sources?

Comment: Do a clean build: CMD+K and then try again?

Comment: A header file cannot be itself a "compiled source", it's not (by itself) a translation unit. It may be *part* of a translation unit, when a module (a .m file for example) imports it (either directly or indirectly).

Answer (score 0):

A deep clean did the trick (not the same as Product > Clean) - Option+Command+Shift+K